# when the popup closes I need to add a scroll to the red background div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

1. When I click open first window button a popup opens.
2. In that window when I click the cross icon the popup closes.
3. When the popup closes I need to add a scroll to the red background div.

Can you guys tell me how to add it? Providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/7n77r6ue/

```
$("#open1").click(function() {
    $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "500px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Window 1"
    });
});

$("#open2").click(function() {
    $("#win2").show().kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "500px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Window 2"
    }).data("kendoWindow").center();
});

$("#close2").click(function() {
    $("#win2").data("kendoWindow").close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function on close event of the window, simply by putting it into the options:

```
$("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 1",
    close: functionOnClose     // Call a function on close of the window
});
```

To add a scrollbar, you can use jQuery:

```
$(".scrollWindow").css("overflow-y","scroll");
```

(The scrollbar will be inactive, except if the div is higher than the viewport, but it will appear.)

Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/wrvj1p44/

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how to test and see it...I am confused...can you upload screenshot so that I will keep the screen to that size and see it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Get a scrollbar for the red div?  Check out the jsFiddle I linked to

Comment: when I close the window 1 popup a scroll bar should appear to the red div.. for all scenarios... whether its viewport or not

Comment: Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ldqunmpa/  Do you see the scrollbars?  (I just removed the `y` from `overscroll` so you have the scrollbar for both vertical and horizontal.)

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot...it's hard for me to test